# что делать с игрой pygame?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

я недавно познакомился с программированием и написал свою первую игру на python при помощи библиотеки pygame. После того как я её доделал, я задался вопросом: а что с ней делать дальше? Не буду же я например, размещать на своём сайте исходный код игры со спрайтами.

Comment: Зависит от того, какой результат вы хотите получить. Можно никуда не выкладывать. Можно выложить вместе с исходным кодом под какой-нибудь opensource лицензией.

Comment: @insolor я думаю он имеет введу, как ее выложить в интернет чтобы ее можно было скачать, там же без исходников надо выкладовать

Comment: И да Vyacheslav, если первый язык Python - это ОЧенЬ ПлохО!

Comment: @Данил, если надо чтобы кто-то смог скачать и запустить - то в случае интерпретируемых языков выкладывание вместе с исходниками тоже вариант. "если первый язык Python - это ОЧенЬ ПлохО!" - это ерунда. Без разницы с какого языка начинать, главное начать.

Comment: Но конечно с Turbo Pascal в 2020 лучше не начинать) А с Python - вполне можно, очень советую.

Comment: @insolor ну я как тру-программист отрицаю это

Comment: @Данил, тру-программисты вырастают, заканчивают институты и становятся обычными разработчиками (да, аппеляция к возрасту). А если серьезно, то нужно уметь аргументировать свое мнение. "Я тру-программист, значит это правильно" - не прокатит.

Comment: @Данил А с чего по-вашему надо начинать?

Comment: @VictorVosMottorthanksMonica я полагаю с машинных кодов и перфокарт

Comment: @VictorVosMottorthanksMonica С С++ ведь, если ты его выучишь тебе не составит труда выучить другой

Comment: @Данил, правильно, новичок должен сначала испытать всю боль ручного управления памятью, чтобы потом без труда и с облегчением перейти на любой другой язык.

Comment: @insolor я тут чую рофл, или мне кажется?

Comment: @Данил нет, это отголоски пережитой на себе боли.

Comment: @insolor я даже ассемблер пытался учить, но не получилось и hello world написать))